# can I add 2 Banner ads in a single activity

Tags: android, admob, banner-ads

I am new to Android and AdMob. I wanted to know can I add 2 banners one at the top and one at the bottom of the activity at the same time? My second question is, I am using a Banner ad in my custom dialog. The activity below the dialog also has a banner at the bottom of the activity. Is that against the AdMob Policies?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to load multiple Banner Ads in a single activity. However, for concerns specific to permissible implementations when using the AdMob and the Mobile Ads SDK, it's best to raise this over to the Product Support Team